# Entity Framework and System.Data.Sqlite Datetime issue

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, datetime, system.data.sqlite

I have a problem with mapping existing sqlite3 database (over system.data.sqlite) with entity framework (version 5) code first.

There is a table in database called notes that I map to my entity class:

```
public class Note
{   
    [Column("ZNAME")
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("ZDATE")]
    public DateTime Date  { get; set; }

    [Column("ZNOTE")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

In database for example I have 2 rows, one has ZDATE field empty, other has some date (example: 30/12/1899 21:00:05).
When I unit test it, and when trying to get whole collection or this first row with empty datetime field I get the infamous exception: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." Trying to get only other row (with date), my test passes.

At first I thought that changing DateTime to string will solved the problem, but it gives me the same exception. I tried using DateTime?, same error.

It looks like, maybe I'm wrong, that System.Data.Sqlite tries to convert that field to datetime (because of name or something).

This is the stacktrace of my exception:

```
at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExactMultiple(String s, String[] formats, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
   at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String[] formats, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConvert.ToDateTime(String dateText, SQLiteDateFormats format, DateTimeKind kind)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConvert.ToDateTime(String dateText)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConvert.ToDateTime(IntPtr ptr, Int32 len)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.GetDateTime(SQLiteStatement stmt, Int32 index)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.GetValue(SQLiteStatement stmt, Int32 index, SQLiteType typ)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetUntypedValueDefault(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetPropertyValueWithErrorHandling[TProperty](Int32 ordinal, String propertyName, String typeName)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Can someone give me some insight how to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you got the right `DateTimeFormat` in the connection string?

Comment: @Redbull Did you fixed it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DateTime? as the type

```
[Column("ZDATE")]
public DateTime? Date  { get; set; }
```

This will allow null values for the Date field

Comment: If it's still giving you an error then I'm afraid I can't help, however you MUST use a nullable DateTime field. An empty string/null value will never map to DateTime and will always give an error.

Comment: Did you find out what the problem was?

Comment: Not yet, nothing worked for know, and I don't want a workaround...I think it is maybe an system.data.sqlite missing case. Problem is, at least I think, that if your "string" for date isn't one of the formats, exception is thrown. When its empty it shouldn't be an exception, just a null or something...

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, [dates must have the format `yyyy-mm-dd`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: They can have more formats, because this is read normally (11/11/2011), but that is not the problem.

I'm using existing database, where some ZDATE fields are empty (atleast sqliteadmin app is showing them empty), and I must not change that...